# How to save a string to a .txt file in java

Tags: java, save

Ive finished an application and have tested all the functions and they are working. However one part of inputted data is supposed to be saved to a .txt file. Ive placed this inside a string but Im a bit out of my depth in this area and have no idea how to save this to a drive on my PC. Any help is appreciated. The code is on this link: http://sharetext.org/fSy2

Comment: Check `FileOutputStream` , `BufferedWriter`, `FileWriter`

Comment: And if you have Apache commons IO lib you can use `FileUtils.writeStringToFile()`

Comment: @Java_User . I believe only FileWriter, BufferedWriter and File are sufficient. FileOutputStream is not necessary.

Comment: Paste your piece of code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {

  File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
  // creates the file
  file.createNewFile();
  // creates a FileWriter Object
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
  // Writes the content to the file
  writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n"); 
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
}
```

Read more abut [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm)